# class re-instantiate on every ajax call in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a file which basically handles infinite scrolls. but each time I make ajax requests, my class get re-instantiate and hence I lost all the necessary variables. results in lading same first post every time.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class File: Infinite Scroll Manager.
 *
 * @package The-One
 * @author Janak Patel <pateljanak830@gmail.com>
 */

namespace THE_ONE\Inc\Classes;

use THE_ONE\Inc\Traits\Singleton;
use WP_Query;

/**
 * Infinite scroll handler.
 */
class Infinite_Scroll {
    use Singleton;

    /**
     * Represents current pages number served to the front-end.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private static $reading_page = 1;
    /**
     * Represents the maximum number of pages available to serve.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private static $book_length = 1;
    /**
     * Represents if last page of the total available pages has served?
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    private static $end_of_book = false;

    /**
     * Class constructor, setups the hooks and class static variable
     */
    private function __construct() {
        $this->setup_hooks();
        $this->book_length_setter();
    }

    /**
     * Hook-ins the ajax handling methods.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setup_hooks() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_infiscroll', [ $this, 'ajax_feeder' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_infiscroll', [ $this, 'ajax_feeder' ] );
    }

    /**
     * `book_length` private varible setter method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function book_length_setter() {
        $max_pages = wp_count_posts();
        if ( $max_pages ) {
            self::$book_length = intval( ceil( ( $max_pages->publish ) / 4 ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setter function for `reading_page` (class private variable).
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function next_page() {
        // phpcs:ignore 
        self::$reading_page += 1; // because `+=1` is more readable here.
    }

    /**
     * Resets the current served page to value 1
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function fresh_read() {
        self::$reading_page = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Verifies and handles the incoming ajax requests. Calculates which page will be served next.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function ajax_feeder() {
        if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'infinite_scroll_nonce', 'ajax_nonce', false ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( 'Invalid security token.', 'the-one' ) );
            wp_die( '0', 400 );
        }

        if ( ! self::$end_of_book ) {

            $this->next_page();
            $this->give_feeds( self::$reading_page );

            if ( self::$reading_page === self::$book_length ) {
                self::$end_of_book = true;
                wp_die( 'END_OF_BOOK' );
            }
            wp_die();
        }

        wp_die( 'END_OF_BOOK' );

    }

    /**
     * Serves the post data of the given page number
     *
     * @param integer $page_no : page number of which posts to be served.
     * @return void
     */
    public function give_feeds( $page_no = 1 ) {
        $index = 1;

        if ( 1 <= $page_no && self::$book_length >= $page_no ) {
            $index = $page_no;
        }

        $args = [
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'paged'          => $index,
        ];

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts\posts\article' );
            }
            echo '<div id="load-trigger"></div>';
            echo $index;
            echo self::$book_length;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        if ( self::$reading_page !== $index ) {
            self::$reading_page = $index;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to retain those variables, kindly help me.

And for reference checkout the below written JS code.

```
(   
    function infinite_scroll() {
        let safetyLock = false; // To prevent multiple triggers for same page.
        
        document.addEventListener( 'scroll', event=>{
            const trigger = document.getElementById( 'load-trigger' );
            check_for_trigger_push( trigger ) && ! safetyLock ? ajax_caller( trigger ) : '';
            return '';
        } )
        
        function check_for_trigger_push( trigger ){
            if ( trigger ) {
                const location = trigger.getBoundingClientRect();
                const clientHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                return (
                    location.top >= 0 &&
                    location.left >= 0 &&
                    location.bottom <= 1.5 * parseInt( clientHeight )  &&
                    location.right <= ( window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth )
                );
            }
            return false;
        }

        function ajax_caller( trigger ) {
            safetyLock = true;
            const url   = siteConfig?.ajax_url   ?? '';
            const nonce = siteConfig?.ajax_nonce ?? '';
    
            if( url && nonce ){
                let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                        trigger.remove();
                        safetyLock = false;
                        let response = this.response;
                        console.log( response )
                        try {
                            let suspect = JSON.parse(response);
                            if ( ! suspect.success ) {
                                location.reload()
                            }
                        } catch( error ) {
                            if( 'END_OF_BOOK' === response.slice( -11, ) ){
                                safetyLock = true; 
                                response = response.slice( 0, -11 );
                            }
                            let access_point = document.getElementById( 'append_here' );
                            if( access_point ){
                                const div = document.createElement( 'div' );
                                div.innerHTML = response;
                                access_point.append( div );
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
                ajax.open( 'POST', url, true );
                ajax.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
                ajax.send( 'action=infiscroll&ajax_nonce='+nonce )
            }
        }
    }
)();
```

- Tried Static properties, but not sure I have tried correctly,
- Tried to set Global variables outside the class but it did not worked either.
- BTW my php version is 7.4.X

Comment: Every request to the server (Ajax or not) is a fresh request and your app boots up from scratch. If you want to keep data between requests, you can store the info in a session, which is persistant between requests for a user. Another solution, more common and in my opinion better, in cases like yours, is that the JS code keeps track of what it needs and sends it to the server. If you have pagination, the server returns the data, the previous, current and next page number. When the user clicks "next", you then pass the next page number you got from the previous response and so on.